# extracting jpg timecode data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime

Suppose in the properties of a jpg file, it says:

```
Created: Wednesday, December 23, 2015, 3:02:38 PM
```

Is there a way in MATLAB to access this timestamp information and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`imfinfo` command](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html):

```
info = imfinfo('myImage.jpg')
```

The field `FileModDate` in the `info` structure array should provide the information you're looking for.

```
lastModifiedDate = getfield(info, 'FileModDate')
```

Comment: It gives the 'when modified' but not the 'when created' field. How to convert the info.FileModDate into a single numeric value?

Comment: That is a limitation of the `imfinfo` command. Your second question is a whole new question entirely. You variable `lastModifiedDate` will be a string on form (e.g.) `24-Dec-2015 01:17:19`. How do you want to convert this to a single numeric value? Do you want to count the total number of seconds, hours? Look into trimming the string into substrings and thereafter using e.g. `str2num` to extract your results.